# SAPUI5 access getProperty() of Json Model (undefined). The Model itself is accessible

Tags: json, sapui5

I can't access my JSON model which has been defined in the manifest.json.

My JSON data "zCatsTestJ" looks like this:

```
{
    "d": {
        "results": [{
            "status": "30",
            "skostl": "6210",
            "catshours": "2.50",
            "ktext": "-",
            "counter": "000003484040",
            "mandt": "101",
            "pernr": "00015822",
            "usrid": "-",
            "workdate": "\/Date(1477267200000)\/",
            "raufnr": "6000025",
        }, {
            "status": "30",
            "skostl": "6210",
            "catshours": "2.50",
            "ktext": "-",
            "counter": "000003484040",
            "mandt": "101",
            "pernr": "00015822",
            "usrid": "-",
            "workdate": "\/Date(1477267200000)\/",
            "raufnr": "6000025",
        }]

    }
}
```

The model seems to be accesible as sJsonDate1 is showing me the data in the console but I can't access a single date. In the end I want to loop over those dates and change the formatting.

```
var sJsonDate1 = this.getOwnerComponent().getModel("zCatsTestJ");
var sJsonDate2 =this.getOwnerComponent().getModel("zCatsTestJ").getProperty("/d/results/1/workdate");
console.log(sJsonDate1);
console.log(sJsonDate2);
```

Here is the console output where I can see the complete data.

[Console sJsonDate1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kQkWg.png)

But when I try to access one datapoint it says undefined

[Console sJsonDate2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ytAtp.png)

I have also instatiated the Model directly in the component and it is working fine. When I compare the model object from getOwnerComponent() and the new one they are nearly the same except for the local one having no aBindings

[Model comparison in console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sdXTH.png)

Any help will be highly apreciated. Thanks

Comment: Did you try :

this.getOwnerComponent().getModel("zCatsTestJ").getData() .... ?

Comment: Thanks for you comment. Yes I have tried getData() also. But it shows only an empty "{}" in the console output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution. Somehow the JsonModel was too big (667 Data Points) and wasn't loaded on the time of calling it. That's why it has worked with only two entries.

```
myModel.attachRequestCompleted(function() {
                    var sJsonDate = myModel.getProperty("/d/results/1/workdate");
                    console.log(sJsonDate);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Your JSON is invalid, status is missing " and you never close the array. I tried it locally after correcting your JSON and it worked fine on my end.

```
var json = {
    "d": {
        "results": [
        {
            "status": "30",
            "skostl": "6210",
            "catshours": "2.50",
            "ktext": "-",
            "counter": "000003484040",
            "mandt": "101",
            "pernr": "00015822",
            "usrid": "-",
            "workdate": "\/Date(1477267200000)\/",
            "raufnr": "6000025",
        }, {
            "status": "30",
            "skostl": "6210",
            "catshours": "2.50",
            "ktext": "-",
            "counter": "000003484040",
            "mandt": "101",
            "pernr": "00015822",
            "usrid": "-",
            "workdate": "\/Date(1477267200000)\/",
            "raufnr": "6000025",
        }]

    }
};
            var myModel = new JSONModel(json);
            this.getView().setModel(myModel, "test");
            this.getView().getModel("test").getProperty("/d/results/1/workdate"); "/Date(1477267200000)/"
```

Comment: Hi Daniel, thanks for your feedback. This was an error due to making the JSON a little smaller (>600 datapoints in the original). In my webIDE project this is correct and I get the error. Do you have any other idea? I can see all datapoints in the console output, but when I try to access them with getProperty() I says undefined

Comment: Have you tried going step by step on the getProperty method (e.g. first try getProperty("/"), then getProperty("/d"), etc.) and see where it fails ? Or do all getProperty calls fail ?

Comment: I did. getProperty("/") shows me an empty object in the console and getProperty("/d") is undefined. I'm currently doing this in WebIDE personal eiditon 170330 and UI version is 1.4.0. I will try this again later in the SCP edition of WebIDE.

Comment: Have you tried retrieving the model through the view and not the getOwnerComponent method ? Not sure about version 1.4.0 but I know that in previous versions you could not access the model through the ownerComponent.
I have serious doubts that will fix it but try.
Can you access the data through the getData() method or the .oData property ?

Comment: I tried both getData() and .odata property. I tried initially with getview().getModel() but this hasn't worked because I'm doing this onInit() of the component and the model is only available in the OwnerComponent at this time. I have also updated my initial post with another screenshot. I have instantiated the Model (like you did) inside the component and there I can access it. If i compare both objects they look nearly the same except of the aBindings

Comment: Where in the code do you do this?  var sJsonDate1 = this.getOwnerComponent().getModel("zCatsTestJ"); In Controller.init function? or somewhere else later

Comment: i believe you cannot do this in controller.onInit because there is a network call to fetch the data. you can get the model and do attachRequestCompleted

Comment: Since the reason you are trying to access the dates is to format them, why not do it on the component you are displaying them ? You can implement a custom formatter and format them at will. Do they not show on the component you are trying to display them ?
@user3808826 He's working with a JSON Model so there shouldn't be any problem accessing it in the OnInit method, I have previously done this.